# Find an expression of $Err(C^*(X))$ using only $\mu_{1}$, $\mu_{0}$,$\Sigma$ and $\Phi(u)$

Tags: classification, bayes-error

$$X \mid(Y=k) \sim N\left(\mu_{k}, \Sigma\right) \text { for } k=1,0.$$
I have found, $$Err(C^*(X)) =  \int_{-\infty}^{x^*} P(X=x|Y=1) \,dx$$ where $x^* = \frac{\mu_1+\mu_0}2$. But I need to express $Err(C^*(X))$ as the integral of univariate distribution $\Phi(u)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{u} e^{-t^{2} / 2} dt$. Find an expression of $Err(C^*(X))$ using only $\mu_{1}$, $\mu_{0}$,$\Sigma$ and $\Phi(u)$.

Comment: Is this homework?